# Django - how to get user from built in LoginView

Tags: django

I simply want to grab the user after login but for some reason can't think of the best way to do that while using class based LoginView. I just want to flash a message with the specific user who logged in. I am not sure how to grab the request.user from the built in login view. So something like f'Welcome {self.user.username}' but everything I have tried so far doesn't work.

My very simple view is as follows:

```
class MyLoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    success_message = 'Welcome'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django Message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/).

```
from django.contrib import messages
class MyLoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    success_message = 'Welcome'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Add message here"""
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, f"{self.success_message}, {self.request.user.username}")
        super().form_valid(form)
```

In your template file, extract the message as below:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Feel free to change the html layout of showing the message.

Comment: I understand the logic for this one but it doesn't actually change the success_message for some reason

Comment: Do you use normal form submission or ajax based form submission ?

Comment: I use normal form submission

Comment: You can use Django's message framework. I have updated my answer

Comment: Yes thank you, I have a slightly modified version if that message template in my html. With your solution in the original answer I unfortunately get NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Yep. It was supposed to be self.request.. But happy to know my solution worked. :)

Comment: Well my friend, sorry to say again but now the message that gets returned is just the comma, I originally added return super().form_valid(form) because I was getting a NoneType error but maybe that was the wrong thing to do haha?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user with `self.request.user`. I am not sure that this is really what you want but you can try to override form_valid method in `LoginView` something similar to this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    messages.success(self.request, "You are logged in.")
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: this sort of works haha, it doesn't actually return the username when I login though. I essentially just want it to say f'Welcome {self.user.username} or however it is you access the username. With this method it returns AnonymousUser instead of the username for whatever reason

Comment: This context is about django messages framework. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/). You can return `f"Welcome {self.request.user.username}"` as a message. Also you can try to provide extra content to your view that comes from `ContextMixin`. If you dont like messages framework add these field to your view `extra_context = {"login_message": f"Welcome {self.request.user}"}` and use it in your template as ```{% if login_message %} {{ login_message }}  {% endif %}```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions I will definitely try these and google some more!

Answer (score 0):

You can access current user as,

```
self.request.user
```

Comment: How though? When I try my different ways in my view I just get undefined variable issues. This is what confused me originally, I understand that behind the scenes django will take in a request. But because I don't specify it in as args in the class based view I am not entirely sure how to access it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you do it in one of methods of this class by using `self.request.user` construction , or `self.request.user.username`

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the success message, so if the user is logged in you could access the request object while creating your message.

Here's the example from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views);

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import ComplicatedModel


class ComplicatedCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = ComplicatedModel
    success_url = '/success/'
    success_message = "%(calculated_field)s was created successfully"

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            calculated_field=self.object.calculated_field,
        )
```